# Object Expected Error When Writing Table Dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to write my table dynamically (for later back-end db use) and I am getting an "object expected" error when I click any of the go to buttons after clicking on the "LOAD" button on my page. Theoretically it should work, as I have written my table to the body of the HTML document. I don't see what I am doing wrong here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#mstrWrapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 200px;
        width: 800px;
        border: 1px solid #808080;

        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        scrollbar-base-color: #DFDFDF;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #235A81;

}

#mstrTable {
        width: 800px;
        color: #235A81;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 9pt;
        border: 0px;
}

#mstrTable th, #mstrTable td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
        border-right: 1px solid #808080;
        padding: 3px;
}

#mstrTable th {
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#cdcdcd");
        width: 110px;
        height: 18px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
        border-top: 0px;
}

#mstrTable thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
}


#mstrTable tbody tr:first-child td {
        padding: 28px 3px 3px 3px;
}
#mstrTable tr.normal td {
    color: #235A81;
    background-color: white;
}
#mstrTable tr.highlighted td {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #235A81;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="mstrWrapper"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function writeit() {
var strVar=" <table id='mstrTable' cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">";
strVar += "     <thead>";
strVar += "      <tr> ";
strVar += "        <th>File Number<\/th>";
strVar += "        <th>Date1<\/th>";
strVar += "        <th>Date2<\/th>";
strVar += "        <th>Status<\/th>";
strVar += "        <th>Num.<\/th>";
strVar += "      <\/tr>";
strVar += "    <\/thead>";
strVar += "    <tbody>";
strVar += "      <tr> ";
strVar += "        <td>KABC<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>09\/12\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>09\/12\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>Submitted<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>0<\/td>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "      <\/tr>";
strVar += "      <tr> ";
strVar += "        <td>KCBS<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>09\/11\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>09\/11\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>Lockdown<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>2<\/td>";
strVar += "      <\/tr>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "      <tr> ";
strVar += "        <td>WFLA<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>09\/11\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>09\/11\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>Submitted<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>1<\/td>";
strVar += "      <\/tr>";
strVar += "      <tr> ";
strVar += "        <td>WPPP<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>03\/19\/2003<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>03\/19\/2003<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>In-Progress<\/td>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "        <td>0<\/td>";
strVar += "      <\/tr>";
strVar += "      <tr> ";
strVar += "        <td>WRRR<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>Submitted<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>5<\/td>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "      <\/tr>";
strVar += "      <tr> ";
strVar += "        <td>WTTT<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>In-Progress<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>0<\/td>";
strVar += "      <\/tr>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "      <tr> ";
strVar += "        <td>WYYD<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>02\/11\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>02\/11\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>Submitted<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>7<\/td>";
strVar += "      <\/tr>";
strVar += "      <tr> ";
strVar += "        <td>WRRR<\/td>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "        <td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "        <td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>Submitted<\/td>";
strVar += "        <td>5<\/td>";
strVar += "      <\/tr>";
strVar += "    <\/tbody>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "    <\/table>";

document.getElementById('mstrWrapper').innerHTML = strVar

var table = document.getElementById("mstrTable");
var thead = table.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var ishigh;

tbody.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var td = e.target || e.srcElement; //assumes there are no other elements inside the td
  var row = td.parentNode;
  if (ishigh&&ishigh!=row){
    ishigh.className='';
  }
  row.className = row.className==="highlighted" ? "" : "highlighted";
  ishigh=row;
}

thead.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var th = e.target || e.srcElement;  //assumes there are no other elements in the th
  //alert(th.innerHTML);  ### FOR LATER (DB BACK END USE) ###
}
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || event;
    var code = e.keyCode, rowslim = table.rows.length - 2, newhigh;
    if(code === 38){ //up arraow
        newhigh = rowindex(ishigh) - 2;
        if(!ishigh || newhigh < 0){return GoTo('mstrTable', rowslim);}
        return GoTo('mstrTable', newhigh);
    } else if (code === 40){ //down arrow
        newhigh = rowindex(ishigh);
        if(!ishigh || newhigh > rowslim){return GoTo('mstrTable', 0);}
        return GoTo('mstrTable', newhigh);
    }
}

function GoTo(id,nu){
  var obj=document.getElementById(id),
      trs=obj.getElementsByTagName('TR');
  nu = nu + 1;
  if (trs[nu]){
    if (ishigh&&ishigh!=trs[nu]){
      ishigh.className='';
    }
    trs[nu].className = trs[nu].className=="highlighted" ? "" : "highlighted";
    ishigh=trs[nu];
   }
}

function rowindex(row){
    var rows = table.rows, i = rows.length;
    while(--i > -1){
        if(rows[i] === row){return i;}
    }
}

}//end of nested function
</script>
<input type="button" name="" value="GoTo 0" onmouseup="GoTo('mstrTable',0);" />
<input type="button" name="" value="GoTo 1" onmouseup="GoTo('mstrTable',1);" />
<input type="button" name="" value="GoTo 2" onmouseup="GoTo('mstrTable',2);" />
<input type="button" name="" value="GoTo 3" onmouseup="GoTo('mstrTable',3);" />
<br>
<input type="button" value="LOAD" onclick="writeit()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please try to limit your code down to the relevant sections.  If you're not sure which are the relevant sections, spend some time trying to figure it out yourself first.

Comment: I realize that this isn't within the scope of the question, but I would avoid using so many string concatenations and innerHTML.
http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html AND en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object Just my 2¢

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions are *declared* in `writein()`, hence they are visible only in the scope of `writein()` too.

A quickfix would be to use a *function expression*, which can make `GoTo()` global:

```
GoTo = function (id,nu) {...
```

Maybe the best way to fix the problem is to remove the online eventlisteners for buttons, and attach them with `addEventListener()` inside the `writein()`. Just enclose the `input`s (not the one with value `LOAD`) in a `<div id="inputs">`, then you can do something like this:

```
//end of nested function
var inputs = document.getElementById('inputs').getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var n = 0; n < inputs.length; n++) {
    inputs[n].addEventListener('click', (function (x) {
        return function () {GoTo('mstrTable', x);}
    }(n)), false);      
}
```

Comment: Hi Teemu, what would the coding for that? it sounds promising.